# How to add "partial" ceiling joist to support mini split cassette that needs 16" OC joist

Tags: ceiling, joists, carpentry

Our ceiling has 24" OC joists, and we are adding a mini split ceiling cassette that needs 16" OC joists.

Can I add a "partial" ceiling joist to support the mini split? That is could I add two cross braces/members and then a joist that only spans 5 feet to support the mini split? I've illustrated this in the image below.

Or, if adding a joist would it have to run the full span (20')? Or is there a better way to support the mini split?

[image: Ceiling schematic]

Comment: Is the 16" O.C for attachment screws?  If so one 2x6(on its side) across the two foot space might be enough.

Comment: Yes it's to attach the cassette to with 3 screws into each joist. Wouldn't there be some issue in the rotational force of the 2x6 on it's side?

Comment: The cassettes weigh about 90 lbs

Comment: What is a _mini split ceiling cassette_ ?

Comment: @DDuck "what is *a web search using the terms you put in italics?*"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't even need full 2x6 here. 2x4 properly aligned should provide adequate support. I would use the proper hangers for the joints.

[image: 2x4 joist hanger]

*[Image source](https://mobileimages.lowes.com/productimages/2b10914c-5f2a-4a0e-b3b7-f9fb7228ccab/14907300.jpg?size=xl), no endorsement implied*

Don't think of it as adding a joist, because it's not. You're adding framing to support the cassette, nothing more.